# D3.js how to write pop-out box that appears when the user clicks on an element

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to implement a pop-out box that appears when the users click on a circle so that information about the circle can pop-out and show on the box.

Here is test code

```
var links = [
    {source: "Microsoft", target: "Amazon", type: "licensing"},
    {source: "Microsoft", target: "HTC", type: "licensing"},
    {source: "Samsung", target: "Apple", type: "suit"},
    {source: "Motorola", target: "Apple", type: "suit"},
    {source: "Nokia", target: "Apple", type: "resolved"},
    {source: "HTC", target: "Apple", type: "suit"},
    {source: "Kodak", target: "Apple", type: "suit"},
    {source: "Microsoft", target: "Barnes & Noble", type: "suit"},
    {source: "Microsoft", target: "Foxconn", type: "suit"},
    {source: "Oracle", target: "Google", type: "suit"},
    {source: "Apple", target: "HTC", type: "suit"},
    {source: "Microsoft", target: "Inventec", type: "suit"},
    {source: "Samsung", target: "Kodak", type: "resolved"},
    {source: "LG", target: "Kodak", type: "resolved"},
    {source: "RIM", target: "Kodak", type: "suit"},
    {source: "Sony", target: "LG", type: "suit"},
    {source: "Kodak", target: "LG", type: "resolved"},
    {source: "Apple", target: "Nokia", type: "resolved"},
    {source: "Qualcomm", target: "Nokia", type: "resolved"},
    {source: "Apple", target: "Motorola", type: "suit"},
    {source: "Microsoft", target: "Motorola", type: "suit"},
    {source: "Motorola", target: "Microsoft", type: "suit"},
    {source: "Huawei", target: "ZTE", type: "suit"},
    {source: "Ericsson", target: "ZTE", type: "suit"},
    {source: "Kodak", target: "Samsung", type: "resolved"},
    {source: "Apple", target: "Samsung", type: "suit"},
    {source: "Kodak", target: "RIM", type: "suit"},
    {source: "Nokia", target: "Qualcomm", type: "suit"}
];

var nodes = {};

// Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
links.forEach(function(link) {
    link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
    link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
});

var width = 1260,
    height = 600;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
    .links(links)
    .size([width, height])
    .linkDistance(60)
    .charge(-300)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

// Per-type markers, as they don't inherit styles.
svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"])
    .enter().append("marker")
    .attr("id", function(d) { return d; })
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 15)
    .attr("refY", -1.5)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

var path = svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
    .data(force.links())
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
    .attr("marker-end", function(d) { return "url(#" + d.type + ")"; });

var circle = svg.append("g").selectAll("circle")
    .data(force.nodes())
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 15)
    .call(force.drag);

var text = svg.append("g").selectAll("text")
    .data(force.nodes())
    .enter().append("text")
    .attr("x", 8)
    .attr("y", ".31em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

// Use elliptical arc path segments to doubly-encode directionality.
function tick() {
    path.attr("d", linkArc);
    circle.attr("transform", transform);
    text.attr("transform", transform);
}

circle.on("click", function(d){
    console.log(d.name);

});

function linkArc(d) {
    var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
        dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
        dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
}

function transform(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
}
```

Here, I have implemented in here

```
circle.on("click", function(d){
    console.log(d.name);
});
```

And it can print the name of every node when clicked. How can I implement the pop-out box?

Comment: I think it sounds like you're after tooltips? Check out [this bl.ock](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/a22c42db65eb00d4e369) as it should give you a good starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling for a few days, let me answer this question myself

use popover from bootstrap

```
myItem.on('click', function(params) {
    if (params.dataType === "node") {
        // popover
        $('#example').popover('show');
    };
});
```

In html, add this code:

```
<div id="example" class="btn btn-success" data-original-title="Twitter Bootstrap Popover" data-content="It's so simple to create a tooltop for my website!" rel="popover">abc</div>
```

You can customise the code yourself.